# FileNotFoundError using Google colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Code:

```
X, y = loadData(dataset)

X.shape, y.shape
```

And I am getting

[image: this error]

Comment: It's just saying that it can't find the file path you put in. Make sure that you can access that file using the specified file path through Colab.

Comment: yeah, it seems that it's a path issue. but I couldn't find the content folder in my collab account.

Comment: There's like a file icon on the left that looks like a folder and if you click it, it should load with like a folder with sample_data. From there, you can click the `..` to go back one directory and you should be at root.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort in asking it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show text as text, not as an image of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your file or dataset in your google drive (the same google account that you used for Google colab). Then, you can mount your drive in colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
```

After mounting your drive, you can give the path of your dataset.

```
Path = '/content/gdrive/...'
X, y = loadData(path)
```

The type of load functions that you used may differ based on your data. For example, if your data are saved as .npy format(NumPy array), you can write:

```
import numpy as np
Path = '/content/gdrive/...'
loaded_data = np.load(path)
```

or for .csv files:

```
import pandas as pd
Path = '/content/gdrive/...'
loaded_data = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Comment: my data is saved in the data folder and the dataset file format is .mat...then what should I have to write?

Comment: You can use ```import scipy.io as spio

mat = spio.loadmat('data.mat', squeeze_me=True)```